# Creating nested dictionaries

Tags: python, networkx

I am new in python and still learning and figuring new things everyday. I have a text file that has the following structure

```
2011    1   2   4043.428261
2011    1   3   1129.99031
.       .   .   .
.       .   .   .
2012    1   4   2610.262872
2012    1   5   1526.420342
.       .   .   .
.       .   .   .
2013    1   6   497.5094923
2013    1   7   6666.273778
.       .   .   .
.       .   .   .
2014    1   8   502.258575
2014    1   9   1134.696447
```

I would like to created a nested dictionary that will capture this information in the form of  an yearly directed network graph. fileIn[0] year, fileIn[1] is the source node, fileIn[2] target node and fileIn [3] is the weight. The defaultdict will be used to capture other attributes of the network.
at present I am running the following code that is giving me a an empty graph. Also when i run the short code i get the error networkx has no attribute Digraph.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict 
G = {}
fileIn = open("Data3.txt", 'r').readlines()
for line in fileIn:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    year, u, v, amount = line.split('\t')
    print(year, u, v, amount)
    print(type(u), type(v), type(amount))
    year_id = ('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014')
    #print(year_id)

    year = year_id
    print(G)
    if year not in G.keys():
        G[year] = nx.Digraph(total_lends = 0)
```

Comment: It's called `DiGraph` not `Digraph`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
import networkx as nx
import networkx.drawing
from collections import defaultdict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
graphs = {}
year_id = ('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014')

fileIn = open("Data3.txt", 'r').readlines()
for line in fileIn:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    year, u, v, amount = [n for n in ' '.join(line.split("\t")).split(' ') if n]
    this_year_id = year = year_id.index(year)

    if this_year_id not in graphs.keys():
        graphs[this_year_id] = nx.DiGraph(G)

    graphs[this_year_id].add_weighted_edges_from([(u, v, amount)])

for i, graph in graphs.items():
    ax = plt.subplot(221 + i)
    ax.set_title(str(2011+i))
    nx.draw(graphs[0], with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

plt.show()
```

As @sim pointed out, you want `DiGraph`, not `Digraph`, which is what was causing your error.

Another issue with the original code is that in the loop the `year_id` tuple is assigned to `year`, so the only key that `G` has is `('2011', '2012', '2013', '2014')`.  The edges are also never actually put on the digraph.

Comment: Thank you so for pointing me in the right direction the code works well